# Эффект transition после отведения курсора

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/GnidaGnideGnid/xk25u/1/

Как в данном случае реализовать плавное исчезновение градиента в обратном направлении после отведения курсора с кнопки? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перенесите свойство `transition` из `:hover` в обычное состояние:

```
#btn input {
    ...
    transition: all linear .25s;
    -webkit-transition: all linear .25s;
}
#btn input:hover {
    ...
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Демо: http://jsfiddle.net/xk25u/2/

Comment: Вот спасибо.